# Querying changes that affect a range in a views output without duplicating logic

Tags: couchdb

Say I have a database that stores log messages. Each message contains the information for *priority*, *date* and *message*. An application should be able to query log messages, possibly constrained by priority, ordered by date. So I may create a view called `by_priority` with a key of `[doc.priority, doc.date]`, then I can easily query all the messages with a priority value of at least `$X` with the following request:

`GET $database/_design/$design/_view/by-priority?startkey=[$X]&endkey=[{}]`

Now I want to extend the application to automatically fetch new messages with the given criteria when they arrive. I can do this by adding a filter called `min_priority` that selects message with a priority of at least `$X` (passed with the `prio` query parameter) and making the following request:

`GET $database/_changes?filter=$design/max_priority&prio=$X`

But this means that I have to duplicate the selection logic (minimum, maximum, range of priority, by priority *and* date) on the server (via the filter function) as well as on the client (by constructing the values for `startkey` and `endkey`).

Is it really necessary to implement the same logic twice?

Or is it at least possible to share the code that generates the key-value-pairs for a document between the view and the filter function? This way I could have a generic filter function for each view that calls the view function and accepts a `startkey` and `endkey` parameter. I would also need a way to access CouchDB's algorithm for comparing keys. Is there a function I can access from JavaScript for that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's currently possible to deduplicate code between views and/or filters, although it would certainly be possible to imagine a query server that gives you access to those kinds of features.